# How can i insert a serial number for the following query in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Info**: I want to a serial number to come along with all objects in queryset using Django rest framework instead of object `ID`. The example image is below. the serial start from first object in queryset list.

This is a **Example** i want to get!

```json
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "channel": 25,
        "live_stream_id": "38IEolI8f-w",
        "serial": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "channel": 22,
        "live_stream_id": "S2Oh4cqEmOg",
        "serial": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 79,
        "channel": 34,
        "live_stream_id": "4NfbS0YfuFo",
        "serial": 3
    }
]
```

serializers.py

```
class LiveStreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serial = 0

    def get_serial(self):
        return self.serial += 1

    serial = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_serial')

    class Meta:
        model = LiveStream
        fields = ['id', 'channel', 'live_stream_id', 'serial']
```

views.py

```
class LiveStreamListApi(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = LiveStream.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LiveStreamSerializer
```

Comment: Explain what's wrong. what's the output you get?

Comment: @Art Please take a look my Question is updated

Comment: set class variable `serial=0`, then in `get_serial` method add `serial += 1` and `return serial`. Let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: Can you add the code of the `views.py` file here?

Comment: @Metalgear code is updated

Comment: @Art `def get_serial(self):
        return self.serial += 1` getting syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the additional field by customizing the `get` function of the `ListAPIView` class.

```
class LiveStreamListApi(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = LiveStream.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LiveStreamSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        live_streams = LiveStreamSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True).data
        for index, _ in enumerate(live_streams)
            live_streams[index]['serial'] = index + 1
        return Response(live_streams)
```